# Getting a Value from the inside of a Coroutine outside of the Coroutine?

Tags: kotlin, coroutine

I'm pretty new with kotlin programming and have to complete a tourguide project. I have a hopefully simple problem, but I'm too stupid to fix it, I guess.

In the following code segment I want to use the val "loc" (that's coming from the inside of a coroutine / addOnSuccessListener) as the "startlocation" that is currently set on "LatLng(49.7913, 9.9534)" outside the coroutine. But how do I get that value outside the main thread? Sadly, I can't just do "val startlocation = loc" :(

Please, does somebody have a simple fix for that? Thanks in advance!

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    val routenuebergabe = intent.getStringExtra("tourname").toString()
    Firebase.firestore.collection("Routen").document(routenuebergabe).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener { it ->
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                    val koors = it.await().get("starting_location").toString()
                    val strs = koors.split(",").toTypedArray()
                    val lat = strs[0].toDouble()
                    val lng = strs[1].toDouble()

                    Log.e("RoutendarstellungActivity", "Fatal $lat & $lng")
                    val loc = LatLng(lat, lng)
                }
            }
        }
    val startlocation = LatLng(49.7913, 9.9534)
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(startlocation).title("Marker in Würzburg"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startlocation))
}
```

Comment: I do not understand why you used coroutine inside on complete listener. Since, you do not need to wait until task is finished, because that listener will be called the task has been finished.

Comment: I don't know much about the language. I need to access the field "starting_location" in the firestore document and without that await inbetween the two "get()" I don't know how to get the string from that field. Please enlighten me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to build.gradle (app):

```
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.2'
```

Your code will look like this:

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        mMap = googleMap

        val routenuebergabe = intent.getStringExtra("tourname").toString()
        val snapshot = Firebase.firestore.collection("Routen")
            .document(routenuebergabe)
            .get()
            .await()

        val koors = snapshot.get("starting_location").toString()
        val strs = koors.split(",").toTypedArray()
        val lat = strs[0].toDouble()
        val lng = strs[1].toDouble()

        val startlocation = LatLng(lat, lng)

        mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(startlocation).title("Marker in Würzburg"))
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startlocation))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

You may need to wrap GoogleMap methods if they need to be called only from the UI thread:

```
withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
    mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(startlocation).title("Marker in Würzburg"))
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(startlocation))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me to solve the problem. I used the withContext(Dispatchers.Main) and it's working! :)